# Draw in canvas using selenium web driver not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote the below to draw just anything in a CANVAS but it's not working.

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
 Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(webElement,135,15) //start points x axis and y axis.
     .click()
     .moveByOffset(200, 60) // 2nd points (x1,y1)
     .click()
     .moveByOffset(100, 70) // 3rd points (x2,y2)
     .doubleClick()
     .build();
drawAction.perform();
```

In debug mode this works but normally it doesn't. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

So there is a canvas element in the DOM and below is the HTML code

```
 <fieldset class="signature kyc-signature odd field_with_errors has-
   drawn" data-field="Registration::Field::Signature" data-field-
  name="registration[signatureImageData]" data-name="
  [["legalPerson","firstName"],["legalPerson","lastName"]]">
  <label class="fieldset-label" for="signatureImageData-1a9012cc">
  </label>
 <div class="signature-well">
 <input id="registration_signatureImageData" 
  name="registration[signatureImageData]" value="<?xml version="1.0" 
   encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD 
   SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="62" 
      height="52"><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" 
 stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 61 1 l 1 1"/><path 
 fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
  stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 1 51 l 1 1"/></svg>" type="hidden">
  <a class="clear" href=""></a>
  <div class="signature-container" data-sign-here="">
  <div style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;width: 100% 
  !important; height: 0 !important;margin-top:-1em !important;margin-
  bottom:1em !important;"></div>
   <canvas class="jSignature" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 
 medium none; height: 180px; width: 769px;" width="769" height="180">
  </canvas>
     <div style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;width: 100% 
 !important; height: 0 !important;margin-top:-1.5em !important;margin-
 bottom:1.5em !important;"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="name-underlined"> </div>
</div>
<div class="signature-description"> </div>
```

When running the code, sometimes the draw canvas code work and sometimes not.

Used the below code to wait till the canvas element to be visible.

```
 public WebElement waitForElementToBeVisible() {
        logger.info("[WaitForElement][Visibility][" + waitTime + "s] " + 
       formatLocator());

        // important: nullify implicitlyWait()
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // wait for element
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime);
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver browser) {
                try {
                    findElement(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception while waiting on: " + locator + 
            " " + e.getClass().getName() + ":" + e.getMessage());
                }
                if (webElement != null && !webElement.isDisplayed()) {
                    webElement = null;
                }
                return webElement;
            }

            public String toString() {
                return String.format("element %s(%s) to be visible", 
           locator, locator.getLocator());
            }
            });
```

Comment: You haven't given us any context as to what this is supposed to do. Have you done any debugging? What did you try? What was the result? I'm not sure how we're supposed to help you with this. Are you sure all these coords are within the CANVAS element? If it's intermittent, are you sure the CANVAS is there/visible/interactable before you start the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void drawCanvas() {
        Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", webElement); //Scroll the page and move where the element is located
        Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(webElement, 135, 15) //start points x axis and y axis.
                .click()
                .moveByOffset(200, 80) // 2nd points (x1,y1)
                .click()
                .moveByOffset(100, 100)// 3rd points (x2,y2)
                .doubleClick()
                .build();
        drawAction.perform();
    }
```

Comment: The scroll to view did the trick, since the element was not in view

Comment: Anyone knows how to implement this in Laravel Dusk?